# next-auth with next.js custom provider error: [OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] Provider is not supported

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to setup an oauth next-auth flow with a custom provider, I seem to get the authorization step done, i'm getting the accesstokens and user info and all that, all good, but after that i'm stuck.

On the client side:

- I login on the provider page
  After successfully authenticating I get redirected to the `/api/auth/callback/mycustomprovider` endpoint
- Which triggers the token exchange request function and does the exchange successfully (see this function's implementation below in the "How to reproduce" section)
- I then get redirected back to this URL `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=Callback` and I see the message Try signing in with a different account.
  On the server, I get this error: `[error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] Provider is not supported`

From the docs, this error code is described as:

```
OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR
This error will occur when there was an issue parsing the JSON request body, for example.

There should also be further details logged when this occurs, such as the error is thrown, and the request body itself to aid in debugging.
```

But i'm not sure exactly what the issue with parsing the JSON request body is, i'm trying to get more descriptive logs but also didn't get anywhere, I searched a lot for a similar issue and couldn't find a solution, your feedback is appreciated! Thanks.

Here are the logs:

```
[next-auth][debug][CREATE_STATE] { value: 'AFOAuTezyYLU8gqNb9fPGb21Lt_kVb03TwlCmYlOB1w', maxAge: 900 }
[next-auth][debug][GET_AUTHORIZATION_URL] {
  url: 'https://xxx.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx&scope=email%20phone%20openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fmycustomprovider&state=AFOAuTezyYLU8gqNb9fPGb21Lt_kVb03TwlCmYlOB1w',
  cookies: [
    {
      name: 'next-auth.state',
      value: 'eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..Uq2IBDuGq7p5CdkS.xKJvYi8fkH_v6h-5cj2SjhIEV5rp-dsNObk3O3Ye1gwShw4soPtb26AapD20Nb0s_A0XHPGJxr0K_zQXbsltTtk3Dm6E3UjxogppdaQdAk6p9PVomMvkigepsv3i0hw_LF13JhWpIHQzPGgDSWWCJIWBaQU7qvjs9dbMwBznB42yhJxbm8s.-zAcxzNTxiFpXZaPa8zUwA',
      options: [Object]
    }
  ],
  provider: {
    id: 'mycustomprovider',
    name: 'MyCustomProvider',
    type: 'oauth',
    clientId: 'xxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxx',
    idToken: false,
    authorization: {
      url: 'https://xxx.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize',
      params: [Object]
    },
    token: { request: [AsyncFunction: request] },
    userinfo: { request: [AsyncFunction: request] },
    profile: [Function: profile],
    checks: [ 'state' ],
    signinUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/mycustomprovider',
    callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/mycustomprovider'
  }
}
[next-auth][debug][PROFILE_DATA] {
  OAuthProfile: {
    id: '57aa8faf-2cf6-4280-81cd-bf9e3457e2d9',
    email: 'john.appleseed@example.com',
    given_name: 'John',
    family_name: 'Wick',
    phone_number: '+971551234567',
    created_at: '2023-01-05T00:00:00Z',
    updated_at: '2023-01-05T00:00:00Z',
    type: 'support'
  }
}
[next-auth][debug][OAUTH_CALLBACK_RESPONSE] {
  profile: {
    id: '57aa8faf-2cf6-4280-81cd-bf9e3457e2d9',
    email: 'john.appleseed@example.com',
    given_name: 'John',
    family_name: 'Wick',
    phone_number: '+971551234567',
    created_at: '2023-01-05T00:00:00Z',
    updated_at: '2023-01-05T00:00:00Z',
    type: 'support'
  },
  account: {
    provider: 'mycustomprovider',
    type: 'Bearer',
    providerAccountId: '57aa8faf-2cf6-4280-81cd-bf9e3457e2d9',
    access_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9....',
    expires_at: '2022-01-01T10:00:04Z',
    refresh_token: 'YRjxLpsjRqL7zYuKstXogqioA_P3Z4fiEuga0NCVRcDSc8cy_9msxg'
  },
  OAuthProfile: {
    id: '57aa8faf-2cf6-4280-81cd-bf9e3457e2d9',
    email: 'john.appleseed@example.com',
    given_name: 'John',
    family_name: 'Wick',
    phone_number: '+971551234567',
    created_at: '2023-01-05T00:00:00Z',
    updated_at: '2023-01-05T00:00:00Z',
    type: 'support'
  }
}
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error Provider not supported {
  message: 'Provider not supported',
  stack: 'Error: Provider not supported\n' +
    '    at callbackHandler (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/callback-handler.js:20:57)\n' +
    '    at Object.callback (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:119:48)\n' +
    '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:201:28)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthApiHandler (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:24:19)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuth._args$ (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:110:14)\n' +
    '    at async Object.apiResolver (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:9)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.runApi (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:514:9)\n' +
    '    at async Object.fn (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:828:35)\n' +
    '    at async Router.execute (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:243:32)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.runImpl (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:432:29)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.run (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:831:20)\n' +
    '    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:375:20)\n' +
    '    at async /Users/xxx/Projects/internal-dashboard/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:157:99',
  name: 'Error'
}
```

**How to reproduce**

Here is the code:

```
providers: [
    {
      id: 'mycustomprovider',
      name: 'MyCustomProvider',
      type: 'oauth',
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
      idToken: false,
      authorization: {
        url: process.env.AUTH_URL,
        params: {
          response_type: process.env.AUTH_RESPONSE_TYPE,
          scope: process.env.AUTH_SCOPE,
          client_id: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
          redirect_uri: process.env.AUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
        },
      },
      token: {
        async request(context) {
          try {
            const response = await axios({
              url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/v1/auth`,
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'accept-language': 'en-US',
              },
              data: {
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                code: context.params.code,
              },
            });
            return { tokens: response.data };
          } catch (err: any) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err);
          }
        },
      },
      userinfo: {
        async request(context) {
          try {
            return await makeUserinfoRequest(context);
          } catch (err: any) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err);
          }
        },
      },
      profile(profile) {
        return profile;
      },
    },
  ]
```

Here's the makeUserInfoRequest function:

```
const makeUserinfoRequest: any = async (context: any) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/v1/me`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept-language': 'en-US',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${context.tokens.access_token}`,
      },
    });
    return { ...response.data.me };
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

And the .env.local vars:

```
AUTH_URL=https://xxx.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize
AUTH_CLIENT_ID=xxx
AUTH_RESPONSE_TYPE=code
AUTH_SCOPE='email phone openid'
AUTH_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/mycustomprovider
AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=xxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://open-api.xxx.app:4010
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=xxx
```

Next js and next-auth versions:

```
"next": "13.2.4",
"next-auth": "^4.22.0",
```